# Not able to fetch correct APY in aave mumbai

Tags: solidity, contract-development, aave

I am following this doc - APY and APR - Developers to fetch lending and borrowing rates in mumbai for usdc but they doesn’t seem to be correct and are different from aave staging UI, how can I solve this? thanks